# threading in Python taking up too much CPU

Tags: python, multithreading, io, tkinter, python-multithreading

I wrote a chat program and have a GUI running using Tkinter, and to go and check when new messages have arrived, I create a new thread so Tkinter keeps doing its thing without locking up while the new thread goes and grabs what I need and updates the Tkinter window. This however becomes a huge CPU hog, and my guess is that it has to do somehow with the fact that the Thread is started and never really released when the function is done.

Here's the relevant code (it's ugly and not optimized at the moment, but it gets the job done, and itself does not use too much processing power, as when I run it not threaded, it doesn't take up much CPU but it locks up Tkinter)

```
def interim(self):
    threading.Thread(target=self.readLog).start()
    self.after(5000,self.interim)

def readLog(self):
    print 'reading'
    try:
        length = len(str(self.readNumber))
        f = open('chatlog'+str(myport),'r')
        temp = f.readline().replace('\n','')
        while (temp[:length] != str(self.readNumber)) or temp[0] == '<':
            temp = f.readline().replace('\n','')
        while temp:
            if temp[0] != '<':
                self.updateChat(temp[length:])
                self.readNumber +=1
            else:
                self.updateChat(temp)
            temp = f.readline().replace('\n','')
        f.close()
    except: pass
```

Is there a way to better manage the threading so I don't consume > 100% of the CPU very quickly?

Comment: Your indentation is mixed up, which makes it impossible to know for certain how your code works.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that and changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a new thread every five seconds. If the function you're calling takes more than five seconds, these threads are going to start stacking up on you. Perhaps one solution is to not spawn a new thread every five seconds, but wait for the first thread to finish, and *then* wait fives seconds to spawn another thread.

There really isn't a reason to keep reading the same file over and over and over, is there? Why not read it all once, and keep what you read in memory. Then, when you read it again in five seconds, you can skip over all the bytes you've already read (via `seek()`), and just read the new data that was added. With that, you don't even need to use threads.

It seems you're doing way more work than you need to, when it looks like all you're really trying to do is emulate 'tail -f'.

Comment: That's pretty much it, Would you be able to explain a little more about the seek() function, maybe an example? That sounds like exactly my plan, and also where would you put the {after} command to run after the thread finishes? Those are things I have thought of but don't know how.

Comment: I ended up just using this and one thread at the beginning for just that function, worked well.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to find a supposed performance/threading problem without some code that one can run.

Are you sure that it's threading that sucks up all the cpu? Seems pretty strange to me. If you substitute

```
threading.Thread(target=self.readLog).start()
```

with

```
self.readLog()
```

does it use less CPU?

In case you check for new messages really often, the creation of the thread could be a problem, i suggest you to use only one thread with a loop to check for new messages with some wait/sleep queue/signal based way to trigger a new loop.

Comment: Yes it uses less CPU, but Tkinter freezes up for a few seconds, and then starts over again.